# Geopandas encodings for "never seen before" characters

Tags: python, dataframe, encoding, special-characters, geopandas

during these days I'm struggling with geographical dataframes which I'm managing with geopandas. My problem comes from weird format of special characters that belong to the names of regions and towns. I never saw the format which I'm in front of. Fortunately they are not so many.
I tried to select all kind of encodings, from latin-1 to several ISO-xxx but the only way that appears to work properly is a manual replacement with a dictionary  (which I don't like as it is built only with the examples I can reach from the dataframe itself. If it does change in the future, it will omit that).

Here's an example of how I approached the replacement. Since I couldn't find any good encoding that allowed me to read the dataframe properly, I put the 'utf-8' encoding as a parameter of the geopandas opener.

```
df1 = gpd.read_file('path/to/my/file.shp', encoding='utf-8')
```

The obtained result is the same inserted in the example, anyway. For the sake of the example, I put only 2 instances, beside in my original dataframe there is at least one for each pair in the dictionary.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[b"Pr\x8e-Saint-Didier", b"Vall\x8e d'Aoste"],[ "Bozen", b"Trentino Alto Adige - S\x9ddtirol"]], columns = ['town', 'region']) 
special_chars = {
            '\x9f':'ü',
            '\x93':'ì',
            '\xed':'ì',
            '\x8e':'é',
            '\x8f':'è',
            '\x8d':'ç',
            '\x90':'ê',
            '\x98':'ò',
            '\x9d':'ù',
            '\x88':'à',
        }
df['town'] = df['town'].str.decode('latin-1').replace(special_chars, regex=True)
df['region'] = df['region'].str.decode('latin-1').replace(special_chars, regex=True)
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to handle it?**

Probably it is an existing encoding, so you have several possibilities: check few of such characters in Wikipedia. Some of accented characters have a list of possible encoding. In this case, I found that an old MacOS codepage had some of your characters correct. So I checked other Mac encodings, I think I found it.

Alternatively (and do this if you have many different files and encodings): you can write a Python script with a short conversion table, and iterate all encodings. Select the 3 encodings with better point (and maybe print also the character in such encodings). This is longer on first try, but if you have often such problem, it will help you (especially because it seems you are dealing with old data).

Note: It seems that maybe few guesses of you are wrong (wrong case?).

**What I found?**

I think it is [Mac OS Roman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman). Or maybe some related Mac_OS encoding. Now it is your task to check carefully if my guess is correct (I didn't check all characters).

Note: This encoding is known as `mac_roman` in Python.

Comment: amazing, thanks. mac_roman did worked. That's fun how you defined as "old kind of coding" if you consider that the data source should be the Italian postal service (euff)

Comment: That encoding was used between 1984 and 2001. But before 2000 it was already know that Apple will replace it to UTF-8, so lifetime of such encoding is shorter than the buffer time often it went obsolete. Italian postal service? Is it considered *reliable* like 4 or 5 other nations (so in the "do not send" list on various internet merchants) [Iraq, Nigeria, Afghanistan were the others with unreliable service].